# MongoDB related scaling issue

Tags: java, mongodb, design-patterns, mapreduce

Just FYI, this question is not exactly based on MongoDB, but happens to use MongoDB. I am assuming we might end up using MongoDB's feature such as sharding in a good design, hence mentioning about MongoDB.  Also fwiw, we use Java.

So we have around 100 million records in a certain collection, of which we need to select  all the items which have some data  set to tomorrow.  Usually this query returns 10 million records.

You can think that we have N (say ten) machines at our hand.  We can assume, MongoDB is sharded based on record_id.
The each record that we will process is independent of the other records we are reading. No records will be written as part of this batch job.

What I am looking to do is,

1. Not to centralize  workload distribution across different machine.
2. Fair or almost fair workload distribution 
   (not sure if the following requirement could be fullfilled without compromising requirement.1)
3. Fault tolerance (if one of the batch machine is down we want other machine to take its load.)

Any good solution, which has already worked in similar situation ?

Answer (score 1):

I can speak in context of MongoDB

Requirements 1 and 2 is done through sharding. I'm not sure if I follow your question though as it sounds like 1 says you don't want to centralize workload and 2 is that you want to distribute work load evenly.

In any case, with the proper shard key, you will distribute your workload across your shards. http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/sharding/

Requirement 3 is performed via replica sets in MongoDB. http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/replication/

I would have to understand your application and use case more to know for certain, but pulling 10M records for a 100M record as your typical access pattern doesn't sound like the right document model is in place. Keep in mind that collection <> table and document <> record. I would look into storing your 10M records at a higher logical granularity so you pull less records; this will significantly improve performance.